# Referencing object with dollar sign

Tags: javascript, object

Given the following object, how is the email property referenced? I've been trying variations of getresponse.partner[0].email to no avail.

```
{"getresponse":{"$":{"unpagedCount":"10"},"partner":[{"$":{"id":"p1e","type":"content","name":"myname","status":"active","email":"me@here.com","peopleIds":"9","personIds":"9"},"ketchup":[""]}]}}
```

thanks in advance!
-b

Comment: Formatting it might help, but `getresponse.partner[0].$.email`.

Comment: Note that `$` is a legal identifier in Javascript.  So you can just use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a valid property/variable name in Javascript. Just use it like any other property name:

```js
let $$$ = {
  "getresponse": {
    "$": {
      "unpagedCount": "10"
    },
    "partner": [{
      "$": {
        "id": "p1e",
        "type": "content",
        "name": "myname",
        "status": "active",
        "email": "me@here.com",
        "peopleIds": "9",
        "personIds": "9"
      },
      "ketchup": [""]
    }]
  }
}

console.log($$$.getresponse.partner[0].$.email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access it as a normal key in any JS object via `getresponse.partner[0].$.email`. Note that `$` is a legal variable identifier name, as you can check in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names).

```
var obj = {"getresponse":{"$":{"unpagedCount":"10"},"partner":[{"$":{"id":"p1e","type":"content","name":"myname","status":"active","email":"me@here.com","peopleIds":"9","personIds":"9"},"ketchup":[""]}]}}
var email = obj.getresponse.partner[0].$.email
console.log(email)
```

Comment: You forgot to declare `email`.